# Descending with virtual sticks generate drift problems on Mavic 2 pro

Tags: ios, swift, dji-sdk

I'm using virtual sticks to descend as fast as possible 4m/s but is getting a lot of drift from the wind. I don't know if is something related to the rotors spining at lower speed that can't counter cat the wind or the virtual stick are working in ATI mode. Also checking the apiI found that in the Android we have the option setVirtualStickAdvancedModeEnabled which say "advanced mode will allow aircraft to compensate for wind when hovering" but on iOS we only have setVirtualStickModeEnabled so I don't know if in iOS only works in ATI mode.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Even though the documentation does not list the function to enable the advanced mode, you can check if you are able to set it in your code, maybe DJI just forgot to write the documentation for it.

Additionally you can enable VisionAssistedPositioning to stabilize the drone if you haven't done so yet.

If this doesn't help, try to set the upper cap for the velocity lower than 4m/s and see how the drone reacts to a reduced maxSpeed.

Comment: I have try that but isn't in the code hoever the propertie isVirtualStickAdvancedModeEnabled is there. I haven't tried the VisionAssistedPositioning not sure if it works at hight altitude but I will try. About lowering the speed we try that but the issue persist.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from [github](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS/issues/355) thats works fine. Basically on iOS you have to set the virtual stick advance mode via keyManager as we can see here:

```
func startVirtualStick(enabled: Bool = true) {
    guard let virtualStickKey = DJIFlightControllerKey(param: DJIFlightControllerParamVirtualStickControlModeEnabled) else {
        return;
    }

    DJISDKManager.keyManager()?.setValue(NSNumber(value: enabled), for: virtualStickKey, withCompletion: { (error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error start virtual stick")
        }
        print("Start virtual stick \(enabled)")
    })
}

func startAdvancedVirtualStick(enabled: Bool = true) {
    guard let virtualStickKey = DJIFlightControllerKey(param: DJIFlightControllerParamVirtualStickAdvancedControlModeEnabled) else {
        return;
    }

    DJISDKManager.keyManager()?.setValue(NSNumber(value: enabled), for: virtualStickKey, withCompletion: { (error: Error?) in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error start advanced virtual stick")
        }
        print("Start advanced virtual stick \(enabled)")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: In response to Debali
I'm struggling a bit with swift and DJISDK, I thought i could share an other way I've managed to activate virtual sticks since there is not much to read about DJISDK and swift..

in viewDidLoad:

```
    // Setup aircraft
    if let product = DJISDKManager.product() as? DJIAircraft {
        self.aircraft = product
        // Store flight controller reference
        if let fc = product.flightController {
            // Store the flightController reference
            self.flightController = fc
            // Default the coordinate system to body and reference yaw to heading
            self.flightController?.setFlightOrientationMode(DJIFlightOrientationMode.aircraftHeading, withCompletion: { (error: Error?) in
                if error == nil{
                     print("Orientation mode set")
                }
                else{
                     print("Error when setting OrientationMode: " + String(error.debugDescription))
                }
            })
            // Set properties of VirtualSticks
            self.flightController?.rollPitchCoordinateSystem = DJIVirtualStickFlightCoordinateSystem.body
            self.flightController?.yawControlMode = DJIVirtualStickYawControlMode.angle
            self.flightController?.rollPitchControlMode = DJIVirtualStickRollPitchControlMode.velocity
        }
    }
```

Then I use a function for activating and deactivating the sticks (Deactivating is important because the joysticks of the remote are inactivated when virtual sticks are activated). I use separate functions because I also change the layout (not in the code snippets below).

```
    func activateSticks(){
    // Set flight controller mode
    self.flightController?.setVirtualStickModeEnabled(true, withCompletion: { (error: Error?) in
        if error == nil{
             print("activateSticks: Sticks activated") 
        }
        else{
             print("activateSticks: Error activating sticks")
        } 
  })
}
    func deactivateSticks(){
    // Set flight controller mode
    self.flightController?.setVirtualStickModeEnabled(false, withCompletion: { (error: Error?) in
        if error == nil{
             print("deactivateSticks: Sticks deactivated") 
        }
        else{
             print("deactivateSticks: Error deactivating sticks")
        } 

    })
}
```